# It's Christmas day, I have a gift just for you

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> It's Christmas day, I have a gift just for you,
>
> if you figure out what it is, and here's a clue:
>
> The gift is virtual, but as it's green like cash,
>
> some say it has value, others say it's trash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's

> The **Green Checkmark** (or equivalently reputation)

Explanation:

*I have a gift just for you,*

> Only one answer can be accepted, so if correct the checkmark is just for me

*If you figure out...*

> If we figure out correctly, we get a checkmark

*Virtual... green like cash*

> The reputation gained is virtual, the checkmark is green, we can gain or lose points (reputation) like cash.

*Some say it has value, others say it's trash...*

> Some users bother about reputation and fight for it (XP), while some don't worry about the fake internet points